# DataTable bootstrap Opções

Tags: jquery, datatable

Tenho uma tabela, que quero que tenha um scrollX, quando atingir um limite maximo de tamanho.
o problema é que esta dando erro de reinicialização.
Então eu pesquisei o vi, que o problema era que eu estava iniciando minha tabela mais de uma vez. então quero uma ajuda de vcs, como eu faço para que esses scrips abaixo, fiquem em apena uma inicialização de tabela?

```html
<table style="font-size:12px;" id="tableClientes" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Pessoa</th>
                        <th>Cód</th>
                        <th>Cadastro</th>
                        <th>Razão Social</th>
                        <th>Nome Fantasia</th>
                        <th>C.N.P.J</th>
                        <th>Insc. Estadual</th>
                        <th>Telefones</th>
                        <th>Sistemas</th>
                        <th>Contador</th>
                        <th>Consultor</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <!---->
                        <th>Responsável</th>
                        <th>Celular</th>
                        <th>WhatsApp</th>
                        <th>N° Pcs</th>
                        <th>Servidor</th>
                        <th>Zona</th>

                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>#</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @if (Model != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TipoPessoa)</td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)</td>
                                <td style="width:5%">@item.DataCadastro.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RazaoSocial)</td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NomeFantasia)</td>
                                <td><span id="cnpj">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cnpj)</span></td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InscricaoEstadual)</td>
                                <td width="10%">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TelefoneA)</td>
                                <td>
                                    @foreach (var sistema in item.TipoDeSistemas)
                                    {
                                        <p class="sistema" id="topp">@sistema.Descricao</p>
                                    }
                                </td>

                                @if (item.IdContador != null)
                                {
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Contador.NomeFantasia)</td>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <td>Nenhum Contado Cadastrado</td>
                                }
                                @if (item.IdParceiroComercial != null)
                                {
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ParceiroComercial.NomeFantasia)</td>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <td>Nenhum Consultor Cadastrado</td>
                                }
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)</td>

                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Responsavel)</td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Celular)</td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WhatsApp)</td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NumeroDePcs)</td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Servidor)</td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Zona)</td>

                                @if (item.StatusCliente == Smc.Dominio.Model.StatusCliente.Bloqueado || item.StatusCliente == Smc.Dominio.Model.StatusCliente.Cancelado || item.StatusCliente == Smc.Dominio.Model.StatusCliente.Inativo)
                                {
                                    <td style="color:#ff0e0f;text-align:center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StatusCliente)</td>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <td style="color:#00ff21;text-align:center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StatusCliente)</td>
                                }


                                <th style="width:5%; text-align:center">
                                    <a href="@Url.Action("Editar","ClienteEmpresa",new { id=item.Id })" class="load"><i class="fa fa-eye text-success"></i></a>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="11">Nenhum Dado Cadastrado</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>

            </table>
```

esses aqui são os scripts que eu estou usando. Esse para esconder algumas colunas:

```js
<script>
    $('#tableClientes').dataTable({
        "columnDefs": [
            { "visible": false, "targets": 0 },
            { "visible": false, "targets": 1 },
            { "visible": false, "targets": 2 },
            { "visible": false, "targets": 3 },
            { "visible": false, "targets": 9 },
            { "visible": false, "targets": 10 },
            { "visible": false, "targets": 11 },
            { "visible": false, "targets": 12 },
            { "visible": false, "targets": 13 },
            { "visible": false, "targets": 14 },
            { "visible": false, "targets": 15 },
            { "visible": false, "targets": 16 },
            { "visible": false, "targets": 17 },
        ]
    });

</script>
```

Esse outro para os botões.

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#tableClientes').DataTable();

        new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons(table, {
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: 'Visibilidade',
                    extend: 'colvis', fixedColumns: {
                        leftColumns: 2
                    }
                },
            ]
        });
        table.buttons(0, null).container().prependTo(
            table.table().container()
        );

        table.destroy();
    });

</script>
```

E esse aqui, era o que eu estava tentado usar para o ScrollX, mas só que da erro, quando eu uso ele, porém quando aos demais códigos acima, funcionam perfeitamente, gostaria que alguém me mostrasse, como eu poderia fazer esses dois scripts, e apenas uma inicialização da minha table.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#tableClientes').DataTable({
            "scrollY": false,
            "scrollX": true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente usar o `retrieve` do **DataTable**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#tableClientes').DataTable({
            retrieve: true,
            "scrollY": false,
            "scrollX": true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Tem até um exemplo de na página do plugin bem parecido com o seu: https://datatables.net/reference/option/retrieve